# Отображение модели для редактирования в C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

День добрый. Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше организовать редактирование "сложной" модели в .NET MVC? Проблема с которой я столкнулся - передача данных из браузера в контроллер.

Для "простых" редактируемых полей LastName и Age всё понятно. Далее у нас есть список BookCheckList, на основании которого надо сгенерить набор чекбоксов (BookChecked.Enabled) с подписями к ним (BookChecked.Name) и не забыть куда-то сохранить BookChecked.Id чтобы потом сохранить все это добро в базе.

В данном случае у меня вопрос: всё ли я делаю правильно? Передача полей BookChecked.Name и BookChecked.Id во View сделана через HiddenInput, может быть есть какие-то другие варианты?

P.S. Почему HiddenInput: при валидации модели, если модель некорректна, происходит повторное отображение return View(stv);. Если не передавать свойства BookChecked, то вместо подписей к чекбоксам и Id будет пустота...

Вот что я имею сейчас, но подозреваю что изобрел велосипед.

Модель:

```
public class BookChecked
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}


public class StudentView
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<BookChecked> BookCheckList { get; set; }

    public StudentView()
    {
        BookCheckList = new List<BookChecked>();
    }
}
```

Контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(StudentView stv)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Content("All done!");
    }

    return View(stv);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    StudentView stv = new StudentView() {
        Age = 34,
        LastName = "Фамилия студента",
        Id = 1
    };

    stv.BookCheckList.Add(new BookChecked
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "C#",
        Enabled = true
    });

    stv.BookCheckList.Add(new BookChecked
    {
        Id = 5,
        Name = "Математика",
        Enabled = false
    });

    stv.BookCheckList.Add(new BookChecked
    {
        Id = 3,
        Name = "Агу-ага",
        Enabled = true
    });

    return View(stv);
}
```

View:

```
@model DifficultModel.Models.StudentView

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    @Html.EditorForModel()
</body>
</html>
```

Хелпер для редактирования модели:

```
@model DifficultModel.Models.StudentView

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>StudentView</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.BookCheckList.Count; i++)
            {
                <p>@Html.CheckBox("BookCheckList[" + i + "].Enabled", Model.BookCheckList[i].Enabled) @Html.DisplayFor(b => Model.BookCheckList[i].Name)</p>
                @Html.Hidden("BookCheckList[" + i + "].Id", Model.BookCheckList[i].Id);
                @Html.Hidden("BookCheckList[" + i + "].Name", Model.BookCheckList[i].Name);

            }
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    }
```